# sending data using post in python to php with variable

Tags: php, python, date, urllib2

I have this script and I want to replace the date `2015-05-01` (from and to) with the current date. I am thinking of using **import datetime**  and something like this (I am new to python):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://fme.discomap.eea.europa.eu/fmedatastreaming/AirQuality/AirQualityUTDExport.fmw'
data = "POSTDATA=FromDate=2015-05-01&ToDate=2015-06-01&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken= " 
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

**New script**

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import urllib
import urllib2
import datetime

i = datetime.datetime.now()  // gets the date
url = 'http://fme.discomap.eea.europa.eu/fmedatastreaming/AirQuality/AirQualityUTDExport.fmw'
data = "POSTDATA=FromDate="i&ToDate="i"&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken="  //i replaced the fixed date with the variable i 
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem / question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sound harsh, but being new to a language is no excuse for not learning the language's syntax (quite on the contrary). This line:

```
data = "POSTDATA=FromDate="i&ToDate="i"&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken="
```

is obviously broken and raises a SyntaxError:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
>>> data = "POSTDATA=FromDate="i&ToDate="i"&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken="
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data = "POSTDATA=FromDate="i&ToDate="i"&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken="
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

In this statement the rhs expression actually begins with :

- `"POSTDATA=FromDate="` which is a legal literal string
- `i&ToDate` which is parsed as "`i`" (identifier) "`&`" (operator) "`ToDate`" (identifier)

The mere juxtaposition of a literal string and an identifier (without an operator) is actually illegal:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
>>> i = 42
>>> "foo" i
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "foo" i
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Obviously what you want here is string concatenation, which is expressed by the `add` ("`+`") operator, so it should read:

```
"POSTDATA=FromDate=" + i
```

Then since "&ToDate" is supposed to be a string literal instead of an operator and a variable you'd have to quote it:

```
"POSTDATA=FromDate=" + i + "&ToDate="
```

Then concatenate the current date again:

```
"POSTDATA=FromDate=" + i + "&ToDate=" + i + "etc..."
```

Now in your code `i` (not how I would have named a date BTW but anyway) is a `datetime` object, not a string, so now you'll get a `TypeError` because you cannot concatenate a string with anything else than a string (hopefully - it wouldn't make any sense).

FWIW what you want here is not a `datetime` object but the textual ("string") representation of the date in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format. You can get this from the `datetime` object using it's `strftime()` method:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d)
```

Now you have a string that you can concatenate:

```
data = "POSTDATA=FromDate=" + today + "&ToDate=" + today + "etc..."
```

This being said:

- this kind of operation is usually done using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)
- and as Ekrem Dogan mentionned, the simplest solution here is to use a higher-level package that will take care of all the boring details of HTTP requests - `requests` being the de facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries. I recommend you to use `requests` library.

Here, solution of your problem using `requests` library:

```
import requests, datetime

url = 'http://fme.discomap.eea.europa.eu/fmedatastreaming/AirQuality/AirQualityUTDExport.fmw'
i = datetime.datetime.now()

# add as many parameters as you like
payload = {'FromDate': i, 'ToDate': i, 'Pollutant': 'PM10', 'Format': 'XML'}

# here's the magic happens
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

# status code of response
print r.status_code

# response text
print r.text
```

Comment: I just run this script, and got an xml response about 55MB. You may want to narrow your search with additional parameters.

Comment: thank you very much Ekrem!Indeed the response xml is big,i may filter them based on the users location(from the android application i am developing) !

Comment: @mikaeloN glad to help! Hope this was the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the date 2015-05-01 (from and to) with the current date

To replace the date, you could use string formatting. To post the request and to print the response into stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import urllib2
import sys
from datetime import date
from contextlib import closing
from shutil import copyfileobj
from urllib import quote

url = 'http://fme.discomap.eea.europa.eu/fmedatastreaming/AirQuality/AirQualityUTDExport.fmw'
data = "POSTDATA=FromDate={now}&ToDate={now}".format(now=quote(date.today()))
data += "&Countrycode=&InsertedSinceDate=&UpdatedSinceDate=&Pollutant=PM10&Namespace=&Format=XML&UserToken=" 
with closing(urllib2.urlopen(url, data)) as response:
    copyfileobj(response, sys.stdout)
```

In general, consider [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode), to create `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data instead of doing it manually.